# Can REST clients be not RESTful?

Tags: rest

REST is defined by its principle of uniform interface.  Resources are accessed and modified by manipulating their representations.  The uniform interface also implies Hypermedia as the engine of application state (HATEOAS) which is explained by Wikipedia:

> Clients make state transitions only through actions that are dynamically identified within hypermedia by the server (e.g., by hyperlinks within hypertext). Except for simple fixed entry points to the application, a client does not assume that any particular action is available for any particular resources beyond those described in representations previously received from the server.

Essentially a REST client receives from the server links that it can use to create, modify, or delete resources similar to how a human chooses links on a Web page.

I often see examples in tutorials or documentation of how to access a REST API with jQuery that look like this:

```
jQuery.getJSON("/cities/mumbai/events/?month=2009-05", function(json) {
    alert(json[0]);
});
```

In this case the client is not using HATEOAS or other connected aspects of REST.  Does this mean that we can say that this client is not RESTful?

Comment: I think you're basically right. Yep, it's not strictly RESTful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a good one. Because many devlopers struggled with the same problem, Leonard Richardson developed a ["REST Maturity Model"](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) that defines four levels:

- Level 0 - HTTP as a transport system
- Level 1 - Resources
- Level 2 - HTTP Verbs
- Level 3 - Hypermedia Controls

I'd say that to be RESTful, a system must at least have level 2. Level 3, using HATEOS, is often difficult to achieve, even though it would be RESTful in a strict sense.

Don't accept level 1 or even 0, use level 2 or, if possible, level 3.

Comment: This is an incorrect interpretation of these levels. Level 3 is necessary, but not sufficient not achieve a RESTful design. Without it, you simply can not say your design is RESTful in any meaningful sense.

Comment: Source for this claim, especially for the "in any meaningful sense" part?

Comment: Straight from the creator of REST: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Comment: And because most people find it difficult to implement Roys thesis in real life, it is helpfull to have common criteria to judge RESTfulness of a system. I think it is not useful to either implement HATEOS or not be RESTful at all. What would you call a system at level 2? How would you argue that it is better than one at level 1? Discussions like this are suprisingly common in real life.

Comment: Yes, these discussions are still going on, I know :) I usually call such APIs "json over http". That's what they usually are, without value judgement. It is not a case of which is better at all (both have their place), rather, the word "REST" is quite well defined, so why do we feel the need to misuse it?

Comment: Because in 2016, most people mean "JSON over HTTP using Resources" when they talk about REST. The do not mean REST including HATEOS. That's not missues, it is a shift of meaning in common usage. I focus my energy on talking people out of calling RPC like systems RESTful and talking them into thinking about Resources.

Comment: But isn't it a misuse because like @RobertBräutigam said, REST is a well defined word.  It has a real definition and that definition requires both resources and HATEOAS.  But anyway the discussion of the maturity model is about the server.  My question is more interested in the client.  It seems to me that a client that points directly to a resource through a magic URL known by the programmer instead of through HATEOAS cannot be considered RESTful.  Where am I (or am I) going wrong here?

Comment: I don't think you are wrong. I agree that REST as defined by Roy must include HATEOS both and the server and the client. My argument and my answer is about how we deal with the fact that almost no systems in real life are RESTful by this definition. Do avoid using the term "REST" at all because nos system is RESTful? I prefer to use the term an be clear about what a system, both client and server, does implement and what it doesn't. The important thing is for all involved parties to know this.

Answer (score 0):

@leo you shouldn't have use the adjectives "basically" and "strictly" in that comment. Heke is absolutely right. The sample code is definitely not RESTful. If the server changes the URL for example, then the client will break. Among other things, RESTful clients do not hard-code URLs other than the site homepage.

Answer (score -2):

It's restful. 
REST Client provides a simple way to interact with HTTP RESTful resources.
REST-Client - A simple client for interacting with RESTful http/https resources
use REST::Client;

```
 #The basic use case
 my $client = REST::Client->new();
 $client->GET('http://example.com/dir/file.xml');
 print $client->responseContent();

 #A host can be set for convienience
 $client->setHost('http://example.com');
 $client->PUT('/dir/file.xml', '<example>new content</example>');
 if( $client->responseCode() eq '200' ){
     print "Deleted\n";
 }

 #custom request headers may be added
 $client->addHeader('CustomHeader', 'Value');

 #response headers may be gathered
 print $client->responseHeader('ResponseHeader');

 #X509 client authentication
 $client->setCert('/path/to/ssl.crt');
 $client->setKey('/path/to/ssl.key');

 #add a CA to verify server certificates
 $client->setCa('/path/to/ca.file');

 #you may set a timeout on requests, in seconds
 $client->setTimeout(10);

 #options may be passed as well as set
 $client = REST::Client->new({
         host    => 'https://example.com',
         cert    => '/path/to/ssl.crt',
         key     => '/path/to/ssl.key',
         ca      => '/path/to/ca.file',
         timeout => 10,
     });
 $client->GET('/dir/file', {CustomHeader => 'Value'});

 #Requests can be specificed directly as well
 $client->request('GET', '/dir/file', 'request body content', {CustomHeader => 'Value'});
```

Comment: How does the code in your answer explain why not using HATEOS is RESTful?

Comment: Your code is not a REST client.  It is an HTTP client.  Please explain how it is RESTful.

Comment: This is definitely not REST.